# Python floating point error that has left me puzzled

Tags: python, floating-point-precision

I just recently ran into a problem where I needed to append numbers to a list only if they weren't in the list already, and then I had to run those numbers through a comparison later on. The problem arises in floating point arithmetic errors. To illustrate what is basically happening in my code:

```
_list = [5.333333333333333, 6.666666666666667, ...]
number = some_calculation()
if number not in _list:
    _list.append(number) #note that I can't use a set to remove
                         #duplicates because order needs to be maintained
new_list = []
for num in _list:
    if some_comparison(num): #note that I can't combine 'some_comparison' with the
        new_list.append(num) #above check to see if the item is already in the list
```

The problem is that `some_calculation()` would sometimes generate an inexact number, such as 5.333333333333332, which is, as far as my calculations need to go, the same as the first element in `_list` in this example. The solution I had in mind was to simply round all the numbers generated to 9 or so decimal places. This worked for a short amount of time, until I realized that `some_comparison` compares `num` against, again, an inexact calculation. Even if I didn't round the numbers in `_list`, `some_comparison` would still return an inexact value and thus would evaluate to False.

I am absolutely puzzled. I've never had to worry about floating point errors so this problem is quite infuriating. Does anyone have any ideas for solutions?

NOTE: I would post the actual code, but it's very convoluted and requires 7 or 8 different functions and classes I made specifically for this purpose, and reposting them here would be a hassle.

Comment: Not again.  Floating-point arithmetic woes.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the comparison something like

```
if(abs(a-b) <= 1e-6 * (a + b)):
```

This is standard practice when using floating point. The real value you use (instead of 1e-6) depends on the magnitude of the numbers you use and your definition of "the same".

**EDIT** I added `*(a+b)` to give some robustness for values of different magnitudes, and changed the comparison to `<=` rather than `<` to cover the case where `a==b==0.0`.

Comment: How may I implement this sort of comparison for `in` statements? Would I really just have to use a for loop and perform this comparison on each element in the list, or is there a faster way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `list` and add in a tolerance to `__contains__`:

```
class ListOFloats(list):
    def __contains__(self, f):
        # If you want a different tolerance, set it like so:
        # l=ListOFloats([seq])
        # l.tol=tolerance_you_want    
        tol=getattr(self, 'tol', 1e-12)
        return any(abs(e-f) <= 0.5 * tol * (e + f) for e in self) 

_list = ListOFloats([5.333333333333333, 6.666666666666667]) 

print(5.333333333333333 in _list)
# True
print(6.66666666666666 in _list)
# True
print(6.66666666666 in _list)
# False
```

Comment: This way lies madness. You can end up with 3 values where a==b, b==c, but not a==c.

Comment: Are you saying this because the subclass does not override `ListOFloats[n]==<some_float>`? I suppose you could have a unique method name rather than override `__contains__`. I was just trying to answer his specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`round`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round) on both the values in the list and the comparison values. They won't be exact but they'll be consistent, so a search will return the expected results.

Comment: In principle `round` can result in two values that are really close being considered different (think 3.49999 and 3.50001)